# USB communication between an Android phone and a sensor

Tags: usb, communication, arduino, host

I am working on a senior project. The aim is to collect analog data from a sensor and then it should be converted to digital data. After conversion, the data should be sent to an Android phone via an USB port. I did a search about these steps. However, I could not find satisfactory answers.

- Firstly, I am planing to use an Arduino board to do the conversion and USB communication steps. Some new smartphones provides a host USB future. May a cell phone battery provide enough power to an Arduino or some other kind of microcontroller or FPGA boards?
- If it may not, I can use an external power source. In that case, should I use Arduino ADK boards or can any ordinary board work?

Answer (score 0):

All your power questions should be answered by the Arduino ADK page under the power section:

http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardADK